# Can't install Catalyst video driver on Lenovo T500 win7 64

Tags: windows-7, drivers, thinkpad

Catalyst crashes at the middle of intallation with message: Application Install: install package failure!

Comment: We need more specific information.  Have you tried install the drivers supplied by Lenovo?

Comment: @Ramhound Lenovo's drivers doesn't works too, because it is only for Intel video card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird Lenovo doesn't offer Windows 7 ATI drivers for that notebook model specifically, but they offer the Intel driver for both XP and 7, yet only an XP version for the ATI. :/

Try this one instead (also from Lenovo): [ThinkPad Switchable Graphics Driver for Windows 7 (32-bit, 64-bit) - ThinkPad](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-73641)